# Hadoop distcp command

Tags: hadoop

Am trying to copy the data from one cluster to another through the below command but am unable to do so,

hadoop distcp hdfs://localhost:9000/LEARN hdfs://cloudera.hadoop:50030/Test

as per the syntax  am right but could some where am messing could some one please elaborate in detail if possible can share me the screens. would be great if you share me in screens as am working in production level. Am fighting for this for almost a  day.

Comment: `unable to do so` could you elaborate what that means? Do you get an error? Is running with success and but you get no result?

Comment: What was the expected behavior, and what was the behavior you got?  We need to know these things in order to help you,

Comment: am getting error i was making some syntactical mistake in the path rather that everything is perfect

Answer (score 0):

When you use `hdfs://` you need to use `8020` not `50070`. `50070` for `hftp`

Try by doing like below

`hadoop distcp hdfs://localhost:8020/LEARN hdfs://cloudera.hadoop:8020/Test`